# regular expression Date time for a birthday

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write an regular expression in c#
that will check a date (DD/MM/YYYY).

Any date (01/01/0000) or (12/12/9999) will be fine too.
The day time must be from 01-12,
the month time must be from 01-12,
the year time must be from 0000-9999
and between them must be "/".

Comment: And how is your RegEx going to react to `29/02/2012` ?  Just use `DateTime.TrParse()`

Comment: Your desired answer is on the first page of a google search.  http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

Comment: Don't use RegEx for this.  Use the built-in parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([012]\d|30|31)/(0\d|10|11|12)/\d{4}$
```

should do it!

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to write an regular expression in c# that will check a date

No, you don't need to write a regular expression to check a date. That would be an overkill. You could use the [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method.

```
DateTime date;
string someDateToCheck = "12/12/9999";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(someDateToCheck, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // the date was successfully parsed. You can use the date instance here
}
```

Comment: Overkill or underpowered (leap days) ?

Answer (score 3):

Can I suggest using `DateTime.TryParse` instead?  Depending on where the user is based, the date format should be different (dd/mm vs mm/dd).  A regular expression isn't great when there's solid, tested existing code to do the job.